# Android Volley Unexpected response code 400

Tags: android, http, android-volley

I am using Volley for a login function but I get unexpected response code 400 for https.

It works on WiFi but does not work on a cellular network and the problem only happens on selected phone models. Below is my code.

```
public void LoginRequest(final String username,final String password,final ActionResponse success,final Action err ){
    RequestQueue  queue = MVolleyRequests.getInstance(mContext).getRequestQueue();

    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.POST,LOGIN_URL,
            new Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            success.action(MError.getError(Integer.parseInt(response)));
        }
    }, new ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            err.action();
        }
    }){

        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("id", username);
            params.put("pwd", password);
            params.put("version", "2.5" );  
            return params;
        }
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
            return params;
        }
    };
    sr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            60000, 
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    MVolleyRequests.getInstance(mContext).addToRequestQueue(sr);

}
```

Comment: which URL are you calling?

Comment: @A.S. Its a https link

Answer (score 3):

Try this out:

```
JSONObject params = new JSONObject();

try {
    params.put("id", username);
    params.put("pwd", password);
    params.put("version", "2.5" ); 
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
        url, params,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        }) {

    /**
     * Passing some request headers
     * */
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        return headers;
    }

};
jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

// Adding request to request queue
getRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
```